# How to change permission to x00 for all the files in the directory/all sub-directories?

Tags: linux, command-line

I am trying to maintain the permission for my self while blocking read/write/execute for other users. Is there an easy way I could set permissions to `x00` for all my files? And will that hurt anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forget who originally pointed this out, feel free to comment if this looks familiar (I think it was on unix.stackexchange.com?), but this is what I use to recursively change permissions...

Files:

```
find /home/user -type f -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod 644
```

Directories:

```
find /home/user -type d -print0 | sudo xargs -0 chmod 2755
```

Change the permissions to whatever you want. Typically 600 for files and 700 for directories to remove group/other access. `chmod go-a` to remove group and other permissions and leave owner permissions unchanged (thanks to TOOGAM for the suggestion in the comments).

As for whether this will cause problems, I don't think I can answer that for you with any certainty. You need to think about how these files and directories are used. Group access will be removed, no one other than the owner will even be able to browse the directories (including software that isn't run as your user or root). So... it's entirely possible that it could have unintended consequences.

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering whether there is a way to *soft* assign whether it is a `700` or `600`. For example, if a file is `755` now, it should be `700`; while if it is a `644`, it should be `600` instead of `700`.

Comment: You mean to make sure scripts and such stay executable? Maybe, but I don't think I'm skilled enough to come up with it.

Comment: @JohnM. : sure.  "chmod go-a".  user-level permission bits are unaffected.

Comment: @TOOGAM Good call, I was making it more complicated in my head than it needed to be

Comment: @TOOGAM Thanks! I tried this but got `chmod: invalid mode: ‘go-a’`. Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Comment: @John Try `chmod go-rwx`

Comment: @Bosley That works! Any idea on why this happened? Also it should be fine to merge files and dirs by `find some_dir -print0 | xargs -0 chmod go-rwx`?

Comment: Not 100% sure, `go-a` should be equivalent to `go-rwx` as far as I know. As for the command in this case you can just do `chmod go-rwx -R some_dir`. The -R makes it recursive. It's not necessary to use the more complicated commands in my answer if you don't need to change files and directories separately.

Comment: @JohnM. The a stands for "all", referring to r and w and x.  At least, in some versions of chmod.  It isn't terribly unsurprising that some versions of Unix software may support features others don't; the flip side is that some versions of Unix software may lack features that others don't.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like `chmod -R go-rwx *` work for you?

Asking if it will hurt anything makes me suspect that you want to do this on a directory under `/etc`, `/usr` or something similar. If this is the case - don't do it. If you're just running it on data in your home directory or something similar though then it shouldn't harm anything (although obviously your mileage may vary as it's possible though unlikely you have setuid binaries or similar in your home)